# Acoustic standing waves in a bent tube

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, experimental-physics, acoustics, superposition

Let us consider a tube closed on one side, bent on two thirds and then a big speaker on the other end as illustrated in the following diagram:

[image: Bent tube]

My friend and I have been debating on two main issues:

1. Is this a case of standing waves, closed on both sides, or one side open? Or in other words which of the following is more appropriate?:
   $L = N/2 \cdot λ$, or $L = N/2 \cdot λ + λ/4$
2. Because of the bend, can this still be reasonably approximated with the standard example of standing waves or does this geometry radically affect the equations?

Comment: Consider the movement of the air at the speaker and at the closed end. Not sure about the second point, my guess would be "no" if the diameter is not too large in comparison with $\lambda$.

Comment: @Jasper The movement of the speaker should be compared to the movement of the air at an antinode, which is much larger at resonance. (This is easier to visualize in the case of a string.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a trumpet as an example. The acoustic path (i.e., the pipe layout) is full of bends and reversals which depend on which valve keys are pressed, and yet the resonances are reasonably accounted for by just the overall *length* of the pipe layout- that is, to first order and probably better than that, the bends do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

In considering longitudinal waves in a gas in a pipe, look at how the pressure fluctuates at the ends. An end with a pressure antinode (maximum pressure fluctuation) can be considered a closed end. An end with a pressure node/constant pressure reservoir can be considered an open end.

The displacement node/antinode behavior of the gas will be the opposite of the pressure node, i.e., a pressure antinode is a displacement node.

Based on these concepts, you can figure out which equation relates to your situation.

As far as pipe bends go, yes, they will affect the ideal behavior. How much they affect it depends on the rapidity of the change and the location along the length and pipe diameter. I don't expect a 45 degree bend in a moderate diameter pipe will affect the behavior radically, but will make it deviate from the ideal... Do the experiment!

Comment: I have done an experiment by using 3.2 m long pipe with internal dia 0.076m, no effects in the sound pressure level have been observed when i did the experiment by bending it 90 degree and then 180 degree. but due to pipe resonance same harmonics at the end of pipe. why is it like that?